# I keep getting this value error when creating Ollama Embedding

Tags: langchain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMOQw.png)
Error:ValueError: Error raised by inference endpoint: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=11434): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/embeddings (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x29d6fc070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

i tried this code:
#Using OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings

embedding_function = OllamaEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents(chunks,  embedding_function, persist_directory='/Users/raghavjeendgar/Downloads/embeddings/OllamaEmbeddings')
db.persist()